# Why does const_cast remove constness for a pointer but not for a pointer to a const?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I understand that **`const_cast`** works with pointers and references.

I'm assuming that the input to `const_cast` should be a pointer or reference. I want to know why it doesn't remove the constness if the input is a pointer/reference to a `const int`?

The following code works as expected.

1. **`const_cast` with multilevel pointers**

   ```
   int main()
   {
       using std::cout;
       #define endl '\n'
       const int * ip = new int(123);
       const int * ptr = ip;
       *const_cast<int*>(ptr) = 321;
       cout << "*ip: " << *ip << endl;  // value of *ip is changed to 321
   }
   ```

   But when I try a pointer to `const int` or reference to `const int`, the value doesn't seem to change.
2. **`const_cast` with reference to const int**

   ```
   int main()
   {
       using std::cout;
       #define endl '\n'
       const int i = 123;
       const int & ri = i;
       const_cast<int&>(ri) = 321;
       cout << "i: " << i << endl;  // value in 'i' is 123
   }
   ```
3. **`const_cast` with pointer to const int**

   ```
   int main()
   {
       using std::cout;
       #define endl '\n'
       const int i = 123;
       const int * ri = &i;
       *const_cast<int*>(ri) = 321;
       cout << "i: " << i << endl;  // value in 'i' is 123
   }
   ```

**(1)** works as expected, but I'm unable to comprehend why **(2)** & **(3)** don't work the way I think though the input to the `const_cast` is a pointer/reference.

Please help me understand the philosophy behind this. Thanks.

Comment: All 3 examples are undefined behavior, from CppCoreGuidelines:

Don't cast away const.

It makes a lie out of const. If the variable is actually declared const, the result of "casting away const" is undefined behavior.

Comment: Trying to change the value of a *const object* (`const int`) is undefined behaviour, this is the reason why 2 and 3 don't work. 1 doesn't have any `const int`, only an `int` and `const int*` that points to it, so it's ok.

Comment: @Kaldrr Example 1 is well defined.

Comment: Do you have some objections against the `"\n"` literal? This `endl` macro in your snippets make me feel so uncomfortable :)

Comment: @lubgr `endl` is not a macro.

Comment: @lubgr: `'\n'` ends the line but does not necessarily flush output buffers; `std::endl` does both. While the difference is of little significance at the end of `main()` (where buffers will be flushed regardless), it's a case of "mean what you say, say what you mean". ;-)

Comment: @n.m. - It is in this question

Comment: @VTT nope. Try `*ptr=321;` and see what happens.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm aware of the flushing issue, I was wondering why the OP prefers to not type "\n". The statement `cout << "whatever" << endl;` makes me expect `using namespace std;`  or separate using directives somewhere.

Comment: @lubgr: Forget it, I did not see the `#define endl '\n'` in there -- that *is* strange...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two kinds of constness.

Constness of an *object* is an inherent property of an object. It cannot be changed.

Think of a page in a printed book. It can be viewed as a string of characters, and it cannot be changed. It says what it says and that's it. So it's a `const string`.

Now think of a blackboard. It may have something written on it. You can wipe that and write something else. So the blackboard is a non-const `string`.

The other kind of constness is pointer and reference constness. This constness is not an inherent property of the pointed-to object, but a *permission*. It says you are not *allowed* to modify the object *through this pointer*. It says nothing about whether the object itself can be modified.

So if you have a const pointer, you don't necessarily know what it really points to. Maybe it's a book page. Maybe it's a blackboard. The pointer doesn't tell.

Now if you do know somehow that it is indeed a blackboard, you can be nasty and demand permission to go ahead and change what's written on it. That's what const_cast does. It gives you permission to do something.

What happens if you demand permission to modify a string, and it turns out to be a printed page? You get your permission, you go ahead and wipe it... and... What exactly happens is *undefined*. Perhaps nothing at all. Perhaps the print is smeared and you can neither recognise the original string nor write anything on top. Perhaps your world explodes to little pieces. You can try and see, but there's no guarantee the same thing will happen tomorrow.

Comment: Good answer; but you might want to mention what actually happens here.  The optimizer sees `const int i = 123;` and says "`i` must always be `123`".  This is correct, because there is no way *except UB* to change it.  Then when you use `i` elsewhere, it says "why use `i` when I can use `123`?  That sounds faster!"  Meanwhile, `i` has a memory location, and that memory location *was* modified; in a case where you have a pointer to `i` that the compiler cannot prove points to `i`, it gets `321` as it actually reads the memory.

Comment: @Yakk "Meanwhile, `i` has a memory location, and that memory location _was_ modified;" - No. Not necessarily. Since `i` is `int const` it could be located in ROM and every write access to it is dropped by the compiler because of UB...

Comment: @martin yes, it is UB.  I was describing a common scenario, not a guaranteed one.  (As an aside, outside of main, placing address-taken automatic storage variables in ROM can be difficult; if there is any possibility of recursion eaxh recursion needs distinct addresses.)

Answer (score 16):

(2) and (3) has the same principle, so I'll talk about (2) only.

The line

```
const_cast<int&>(ri) = 321;
```

has undefined behavior.

You cannot modify a `const` object according to the standard, not even with `const_cast`. If you remove `const` from a pointer/reference, and modify the pointed/referenced object, the pointed/referenced object must not been declared as `const` in the first place.

`const_cast` should be used only, when you have a const pointer to something for some reason, and you know that something is not declared as `const`.

Comment: Another use case is to interoperate with API's (often early C) that don't modify the object, yet aren't const correct.

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the constant via the `const_cast` is undefined behaviour.

The compiler sees that you are trying to print a constant variable, knows it can never change so compiles:

```
cout << "i: " << i << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << "i: " << 123 << endl;
```

see: https://godbolt.org/z/bYb0mx. With optimisations enabled it optimises your code to just printing 123: https://godbolt.org/z/4Ttlmj.

Ultimately compilers make assumptions in order to create faster/smaller code, if you enter the realms of undefined behaviour some of those assumptions may be incorrect and produce surprising results.